# Database of competition information

Tags: c#, performance, linq, database

I have the following (extremely simplified) database structure:

- Table: `Competitions`

  - `Id`: string, unique
- Table: `Persons`

  - `Id`: string, unique
  - `Gender`: string
- Table: `Results`

  - `CompetitionId`: string, references `Id` on the `Competitions` table
  - `PersonId`: string, references `Id` on the `Persons` table
  - `EventId`: string
  - `RoundId`: string
  - `Average`: int

Any Competition may hold `n` Results. Each Result is assigned to one Person.

I would like to get all Results (filtered for `Average > 0`, `EventId == "333"`, `RoundId == "f"`, such that it is the one with the lowest `Average` within the other Results having the same `CompetitionId`. Furthermore, I only want to get the Results of which the according person is female (`gender == "f"`).

I currently use a weird mixed LINQ construct that is both, ugly and inefficient. The query takes around 3 minutes on my machine (local MySQL database, Results row count is something close to 200k).

I know there are elegant and efficient ways to use one LINQ query, creating temporary tables, joining and such. I am not that much into it, thus I coded this ugly piece:

```
var femalePersonIds =
    from p in Persons
    where p.Gender == "f"
    select p.Id;

var results333 =
    from r in Results
    where (r.Average > 0) && (r.EventId == "333") && (r.RoundId == "f")
    orderby r.Average
    select r;

foreach (var c in Competitions) {
    var results =
        from r in results333
        where (r.CompetitionId == c.Id)
        select r;
    if (results.Count() > 0) {
        var bestCompResult = results.First();
        if (femalePersonIds.Contains(bestCompResult.PersonId)) {
            bestCompResult.Dump();
        }
    }
}
```

(This is LINQPad 4 compliant)

I would love to see any efficiency, elegance and shortening hints, in case you have some.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you want to throw out the lowest female score in each competition?

Comment: Exactly. Low average is good in this case, don't get me wrong ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm very confident a couple calls to `ToList` will solve your problems. Keep in mind that each interval of the loop will re-evaluate the two queries outside of the loop.

```
var femalePersonIds =
    (from p in Persons
    where p.Gender == "f"
    select p.Id).ToList();

var results333 =
    (from r in Results
    where (r.Average > 0) && (r.EventId == "333") && (r.RoundId == "f")
    orderby r.Average
    select r).ToList();

foreach (var c in Competitions) {
    var results =
        (from r in results333
        where (r.CompetitionId == c.Id)
        select r).ToList();
    if (results.Count() > 0) {
        var bestCompResult = results.First();
        if (femalePersonIds.Contains(bestCompResult.PersonId)) {
            bestCompResult.Dump();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa, I didn't even know it re-evaulates the queries each time. That's pretty much it, thanks! Other improvements would be great too - I would love to see just one LINQ query that does the job...

Comment: Abstractions that leak like a sieve...

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
        var filteredResults =
        (from r in results             
         where r.Average > 0 &&
               r.EventID == "333" &&
               r.RoundID == "f"
         select r).ToList();

        List<Results> bestResults = new List<Results>();            
        var resultsInCompenitions = filteredResults.GroupBy(r => r.CompetitionID);
        foreach (var resultsInCompetition in resultsInCompenitions)
        {
            var bestResultInCompetition = resultsInCompetition.OrderBy(r => r.Average).FirstOrDefault();
            if (bestResultInCompetition != null)
            {
                bestResults.Add(bestResultInCompetition);   
            }                
        }

        var femaleBestResults = 
            from r in bestResults
            join p in persons on r.PersonID equals p.ID
            where p.Gender == "f"
            select r;    

       return femaleBestResults;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this one gets the best female competitors result from each competition. I'm looking for the best competitor who is female. I think I didn't make it clear enough in the thread, let me add some information...

Comment: I've changed the code, and just out of curiosity - is it correct now?

Comment: Yep, works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I may not totally understand what you're trying to do, but here's a go at it.

```
Results
   .Where(r => r.Average > 0 && r.EventId == "333" && r.RoundId == "f")
   .GroupBy(r => r.CompetitionId)
   .Where(r => r.Any(z => z.Person.Gender == "f"))
   .Dump();
```